# Joining tables and getting various categories for each row in MySql

Tags: mysql, join

I have run into a bit of problem. I have various tables that I am joining, but I also need to get the categories for each row I retrieve. I need to retrieve the category id from one table then look up the category name in another table. I think it is easier to show. Here is my failed try of an sql query:

```
SELECT     DISTINCT(t.tour_name), tp.tprecio_precio_adulto, 
           tp.tprecio_precio_menor, category_name 
FROM       tour AS t 
INNER JOIN tour_categories AS cc ON tcategoria_fktour = t.tour_id
INNER JOIN tour_precio AS tp ON tp.tprecio_fktour = t.tour_id
LEFT JOIN  categories AS c ON c.category_id = tc.category_id 
WHERE      tp.tprecio_fecha_inicio <= '2012-10-27' 
       AND tp.tprecio_fecha_final >= '2012-10-27' 
       AND t.tour_activo = '1' 
       AND tp.tprecio_precio_adulto != '0.00'
```

And here are the table layouts:

```
table: tour
tour_id      |    tour_name     
-----------------------------------------
 1                tour name 1
 2                tour name 2
 3                tour name 3

table: tour_categories
  category_id    |    tour_id    
------------------------------------
     1                   3             
     2                   3
     3                   3

 table: categories
      category_id    |    category_name    
    ------------------------------------
          1              category name 1            
          2              category name 2  
          3              category name 3
```

So as you can see there can be multiple categories for each tour, I need to get these categories and group them together then get the corresponding category name for each one. I am lost on how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: you should inner join the category table, and using parentheses to group the joins is normally helpful...you need to think of each chained join as being a join on the previous join/each join represents a new atomic view of the table

Comment: do you think you could give me an example of what you mean??

Comment: you have an additional table in your query that isn't provided in your sample schema, but you should be doing something that amounts to `(TOUR INNER JOIN (TOUR_CATEGORIES INNER JOIN CATEGORIES)) INNER JOIN TOUR_PRECIO`  So bind the category 1-1 matching more tightly and then pull that in to the top level table.  Use parentheses to keep units together, and then pull in the other table in whatever order makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, just in case this can help anyone else. I did a group concat on the tour name, and added a seperator. It works perfectly now:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(c.category_name ORDER BY c.category_name ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS categories, t.tour_name
FROM tour AS t
INNER JOIN tour_categoria AS cc ON cc.category_id = t.tour_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN categoria AS c ON c.category_name_id = cc.category_id
GROUP BY t.tour_name
```